# How to Convert a field in one table to another field in another table when inserting

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox containing a value from mcCentre, how do I convert the value from mcCentre to mcID and then inserting into the doctor table as mcID?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
private int AddDoctorRecord()
        {
            int result = 0;
            // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            String strCommandText = "INSERT DOCTOR(dFirstName,dLastName,dUsername,dPassword,dEmail) "
                + " VALUES (@dFirstName,@dLastName,@dUsername,@dPassword,@dEmail)";

            SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dFirstName", txtDoctorFirstName.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dLastName", txtDoctorLastName.Text); 
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dUsername", txtDoctorUsername.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dPassword", txtDoctorPassword.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dEmail", txtDoctorEmail.Text);

            //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
            myConnect.Open();
            // STEP 4: execute command
            // indicates number of record updated.
            result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // STEP 5: Close
            myConnect.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you get the mcCentre value?  You probably don't want to try to find an ID based off what looks like a description column, as it could change easily

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create drop down instead of text box control so you can pick value while you are inserting doctor record.

if you use text box for mccenter input field then user can type any value in the text box which will not result a match.

Comment: the value in the textbox is will be passed down by the previous form, so the value will be exactly the same as one of the values in mcCentre. just that i do not know how to convert the value from mcCentre to mcID and pass it to doctor table to insert as mcID to database. @Giridhar

Comment: i don't know what type of control you are using in the previous form. if you have value then set the selected value in some hidden field. other option i have use sub query or data looks like master table, so cache the data and retrieve value based on description.

Comment: @Pony since you're passing value from previous form, am I correct in assuming that you are inserting the value in table from previous form? If so, while putting value in textbox for ***mcCenter*** you can also attach ***mcID*** that would be returned from previous insertion to a custom attribute of the same texbox. While inserting values from current form you can very well read it and put in the *doctor* table